# Launch AppleScript from WebView

Tags: cocoa, webview, applescript

I built an AppleScriptObjC app (OS X) that responded to user input and performed tasks on our local server and user's computer. I used Safari as its UI and it worked perfectly until Apple upgraded security to require the user to dismiss a dialog every time the user submitted a form or fired any other event that communicated with the app. This is a major annoyance and inconvenience to my users. Because I have already written a lot of complicated ASobjc and JS for this, I am now trying to adapt it to a Cocoa App using WebView instead of Safari. Because I’m a Cocoa newbie, I  started with an example I found here:
https://github.com/ryanb/cocoa-web-app-example

It displays my HTML and responds to JS events from the window display, but I’m having trouble executing any AppleScript from the HTML. I’m doing a test with a script that just show a “Hello, World.” dialog.

Here is the HTML element:

```
<div><button id="wazzup" onclick="javascript:sayHello('Hello')">Run Hello Script</div>
```

and the JS function:

```
function sayHello(filename) {
    if (window.app) {
        window.app.sayHello_(filename);
    }
}
```

and the Objective C in the AppDelegate:

```
- (void)sayHello:(NSString *)filename {
    NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:filename ofType:@"scpt"];
    NSURL* url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];NSDictionary* errors =        [NSDictionary dictionary];
    NSAppleScript* appleScript = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&errors];
    [appleScript executeAndReturnError:nil];
    if(errors){
        NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", errors);
    }
    [appleScript release];
}
```

When the button is clicked, nothing happens. Can anyone tell me what I’m doing wrong?

Comment: Problem solved: target for the applescript was not set.